How to add Quill keyboard bindings in Next.Js Using react-quill?
I'm trying to add keyboard bindings to the quill editor in my project, however when I add keyboard to the modules object, the editor doesn't show. But when I remove it, the editor is visible again. This is my code:


'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import("react-quill"), { ssr: false });

const DocumentPage = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const modules = {
    toolbar: [
     [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
     ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote", "script", "code"],
     [{ font: [] }, { size: [] }],
     [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
     [{ align: ["right", "center", "justify"] }],
     [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
     ["code-block", { indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }, { direction: "rtl" }, { direction: "ltr" }],
     ["link", "image", "video"],
    ],
    keyboard: {
      bindings: {
        tab: {
          key: 9,
          handler: (range: any) => {
            const tab = '\t';
            range.insertText(tab);
            return true;
          },
        },
      },
    }
  };

  return (
    <main className="p-4">
        <ReactQuill value={value} onChange={setValue} modules={modules} placeholder="Start Typing Here..." />
    </main>
  );
};

export default DocumentPage;



Am I doing it right or is there something wrong?
